# how to change from manual ticks to automatic ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to understand how to I get the ticks to change automatically after I already set them manually:

if I do

```
plot([1,2],[3,4])
xticks([1,2])
```

than the xticks will remain on 1 and 2. and will not change when I re-size the image... how do I delete this manual ticks and go to a state where when I re-size the image the ticks will change accordingly.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of resizing? Additional plotting, or changing the axis limits, or an interactive GUI, or what?

Comment: Changing the axis limits, or interactive GUI. Before I do xticks([1,2]) if I re-size interactively or do xlim(0,10) the ticks will change accordingly. After I do xticks([1,2]) the only ticks that I will see will be 0 and 1 ( I can do xlim(0,1) or use the interactive re-size .. but no matter what I will only see the ticks 0 and 1

Comment: You probably want to choose a different TickLocator that will look good at any of the sizes, then. (Or reset the tick locator after forcing xticks to [1,2], but why bother?)  http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/ticker_api.html